# Python requests http error 600

Tags: python, rest, http

I'm trying to upload a file to remote web site, using the CURL script it's working good

`curl  -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -H "Authorization: Basic cWERF0ZWNoQXBpOmYxZDhmNzJkNDAwNGRjNzZlMTU0NjU4MTQwGRNzc4NTjM0"   -F "data=@file.dat"  http://url/rest/files/upload`

but when I'm trying to use the Python requests lib i got this error:

**`600`org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParsingException: Missing start boundary**

My python code:

```
import requests
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Authorization': 'Basic cWERF0ZWNoQXBpOmYxZDhmNzJkNDAwNGRjNzZlMTU0NjU4MTQwGRNzc4NTjM0',}     
files = {'file.dat':open('file.dat','rb')}
response = requests.post('http://url/rest/files/upload',headers=headers,files=files)
print response.text
```

Comment: No the issue was in the Content-Type.

Answer (score 1):

You must avoid the `'Content-Type'` in your `headers` dictionary. This way:

```
import requests
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic cWERF0ZWNoQXBpOmYxZDhmNzJkNDAwNGRjNzZlMTU0NjU4MTQwGRNzc4NTjM0',}     
files = {'file.dat':open('file.dat','rb')}
response = requests.post('http://url/rest/files/upload',headers=headers,files=files)
```

In this particular case (if the argument `files` is specified) the library `requests` adds the `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` by itself, but with the specification of the boundary at the end. The header then looks for example like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=e8c4b746efb54e2f9ae9412a4402714b
```

By adding `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` to the headers argument, the boundary is removed.

Comment: it solved my problem, thanks. just one more question the Content-Type is treated internally in the requests lib ?

Comment: Good question. It is not. The Content-Type is treated internally only when the argument `files` is specified, because then the boundary needs to be set. There was a misleading sentence in my answer, so I edited it. Thank you.